# Run separate functions in node.js file from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I have a javascript file the that I'm running some node tasks in, and would like to be able to run them separately based on the terminal command I trigger.

For instance, my nodejs file `myFile` code could look like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const fs = require('fs');

const getDbData = () => {
    ...
    ...
}

const fileTransform = () => {
    file transformation functionality
}
```

I'd like to be able to run each function separately, so that I can say `node myFile.js getDbData` in terminal. Do I need to export each of the functions to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply command-line arguments to your script on the `node` command line. You receive them in the [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv) array. Your arguments start at index 2 (`0` is the full path to `node`, `1` is the full path to your script).

So for instance:

```
switch (process.argv[2]) {
    case "getData":
        getData();
        break;
    case "etlData":
        etlData();
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Note that it's true that your arguments start at index 2 even if a Node argument precedes your script on the actual command line. For instance:

```
node --use-strict your-script.js
```

...will still have the full path to `node` in `process.argv[0]` and the full path to your script in `process.argv[1]`. The `--use-strict` argument isn't in the array at all.

---

Or you can put your functions on an object and use the argument as a key:

```
function getData() {
    // ...
}

function getData() {
    // ...
}

const functions = {
    getData,
    etlData
};
const fn = functions[process.argv[2]] || () => { console.log("Invalid option"); };
fn();
```

Comment: In trying to understand your answer, are you suggesting something like this:

``switch (process.argv[2]) {
 case 'getData':
  getData();
  break;
 case 'etlData':
  etlData();
  break;
}``

Comment: Yes, something like that. Or you could use a dispatch object, I've added an example of that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing the update. However, there's an issue with the function after the `||` and how would I run this in the terminal to trigger the functions separately?

Comment: `node yourscript.js getData` and `node yourscript.js etlData` and (to trigger the catch-all) `node yourscript.js anything-else`.

Comment: I've updated my question with your suggested and an error I'm now seeing: `TypeError: fn is not a function`. Any idea what would be causing that? Thanks.

Comment: @user3438917 - You're **calling** the functions and storing the result. Just store the functions: `const functions = { getData: getData, etlData: etlData };` or you can use shorthand property syntax: `const functions = { getData, etlData };` *(I've reverted the edit. On SO, you don't edit answers into the question.)* Hope that helps!

Comment: I haven't had my coffee this morning, thanks! If you update your answer with that from the last comment you made, I'll be happy to select it as the answer for this question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `process.argv`.

https://stackabuse.com/command-line-arguments-in-node-js/

parse the command line arguments and, for example, evaluate them with `eval()`